# Laravel PHP run php artisan serve automatically if something changes

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for a php webproject.

Yesterday I noticed an issue:

Everytime I make changes f.e. in the controller files I need to rerun `php artisan serve`, which consumes a lot of time (close CMD, open it again and type `php artisan serve`)

I am trying to find a way, so this command will automatically rerun when I test my application on localhost.

I could probably write a script or something with Python, which will automatically open CMD and execute `php artisan serve` whenever I click f.e. `CTRL + F5`, but that feels very hacky, is there a cleaner solution?

I also found a guide on how to edit the `hosts` file in `system32` folder and the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in the apache folder, but after doing all steps, if I try to reach my application I get "It works" instead, which is simply an indicator for a successfull apache installation.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `php artisan serve` cause it's just a shortcut to run your Laravel project. For a better development environment, you should use [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead) which offers a complete solution.

Comment: I red already about homestead, but it was too late. I have already setuped everything, homestead cant be the only one solution for this. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Probably you can do it with [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration). Commonly it's used to handle queues but you can use it to fix your problem. You've just to add this [extension](https://github.com/timakro/superfsmon) in your supervisor installation. For more information visit [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/index.html).

Comment: You could also use something like Mamp instead of running php artisan serve

Comment: You could also use something like Mamp instead of running php artisan serve